# WidgetKit safeArea issue

Tags: swift, swiftui, widget

[image]
I'm creating Widget for iOS app by using WidgetKit but I faced one problem width padding or safeArea here is code and output is like this but I want to cover all view by red

```
ZStack {
            Color.red
                .ignoresSafeArea()
        }.ignoresSafeArea()
```

I want to cover red color all view

Comment: If my answer was of help, I'd appreciate it if you marked it as "accepted answer" via the checkmark button on the left :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to set the background of your widget:

```
YourWidgetView()
    .containerBackground(for: .widget) { Color.red }
```